# Changing cx/cy values using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I must first apologise for my potential poor understanding as I have self-taught myself all of my coding and perhaps don't understand certain aspects as well as I should.

I want to input my own value co-ordinates into a HTML file so the mathematical model can work out a percentage chance.

The element is as follows:

```
<circle class="shot-circle" cx="189.3125" cy="160.171875" r="5"></circle>
```

I can locate the element using the XPath but I am struggling to get the .sendkeys() and .SetAttribute() to change the 'CX' and 'CY' values.

XPath:

```
//*[@id="pitch-img"]/circle[6]
```

I have had a look through the python docs and looked for similar solutions such as setting a class value.

My last failed attempt was

```
webdriver.executeScriptdocument.getElementById('pitch-img').setAttribute('cx', '150')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change element's attribute, you would have to *execute script*. Parameterize your script with an element, attribute name and attribute value:

```
def set_attribute(*args):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", *args)

elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shot-circle")
set_attribute(elm, "cx", "150")
set_attribute(elm, "cy", "150")
```

Comment: @FootyStattoWannabe okay, updated the answer, could you try now? Thanks.

Comment: @FootyStattoWannabe ah, my bad, the quotes were extra, fixed now. Works for me.

Comment: by working is it moving the circle on the map? it's not changing anything on the website for me - thanks for your continued help though

Comment: @FootyStattoWannabe are, sure, you want to move the circle. Updated the code in the answer.